# Polar coordinates approach to find continuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

I have to investigate continuity at (1,2) of the following function:-
$$f(x,y)= x^2+2y, (x,y)\ne(1,2) ;$$
 $$f(x,y)=0 ,(x,y)=(1,2)$$
My approach:-
I have considered a circle of radius r around point$(1,2)$ so the corresponding polar coordinates are $(r-1)cos\theta$ and $(r-2)sin\theta$
 Thus at  the circle:-
$$f(x,y)_c=(r-1)^2cos^2\theta+2(r-2)sin\theta=(r^2-2r+1)cos^2\theta+(2r-4)sin\theta$$
$$i.e..f(x,y)_c\le r^2-2r+1+2r-4\Rightarrow f(x,y)_c\le r^2-3 \lt \epsilon+1 $$
Thus $x\lt $
$$\Rightarrow(x-1)^2+2(y-2)\le (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2-3 $$
$$\Rightarrow 0\le(y-1)(y-5)$$
Thus for $y \in]1,5[$ ,the circle of radius r touches curve $f(x,y)$,Thus it is discontinuous at (1,2)
                       
Is my method right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the limit on every curve should give the same result if $f$ was continuos. Which is the limit of $f$ walking on the $(t,2t)$ path? $f(t) = t^2 + 4t$, if you take the limit for $t \to 1$ you get $5 \not = 0$ thus $f$ is not continuos in $(1,2)$.